Azure Container Apps - Dapr process 'daprd' not available
I'm deploying an ASP.NET app (.NET 8) to Azure Container Apps. I want to take advantage of DAPR, at this time, only the state store. All is fine, the API is working and even the state store (configured to use Redis) is working fine. I can see sored values coming in in Redis Insights. However, I added a health check in ASP, which is now failing with the following error:
Dapr process 'daprd' not available
And this is what I can also see in Log Analytics:

Any idea how to get my health check properly up and running? Again, the API itself runs fine, including all DAPR components.
